# Android: how do I test for a RecyclerView list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a UI screen that creates CardViews that are saved to a RecyclerView list.  Initially, there is no RecyclerView list because there are no CardViews initially.  When the first CardView is saved it creates a RecyclerView list to show the CardView data.

I want to be able to test if there is a RecyclerView list already created.  If not, launch the CardView activity for user input.  If there is a RecyclerView list because a CardView(s) was previously created, then launch the RecyclerView activity.  Any ideas on how to test for the existence of the RecyclerView list that I can use with an if/then statement to launch the correct activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom recycler adapter which i think you are(Provide more code if not) , Override `getItemCount()` function like

```
public int getItemCount() {
        if(list!=null)
           return this.list.size();
        else
           return -1;
        }
```

And check the list size and do the functionalities in an if else

### Edit

Check this in the activity like

```
if(adapter.getItemCount()>0)
{
//Do what you want
}
else
{
//Launch the activity
}
```

Comment: Ok.  But if list is not null do I need to test size?

Comment: that is you question right?You want to check weather the item is null or not,Why go for another extra method if you have already written one that can be used for many purposes,like getItemCount

Comment: I suggest you use this one because i don't know weather you are initializing the list in the constructor or not

Comment: I'm wondering if I can just launch the Intent for the activity in the "if" statement rather than return the list size.

Comment: From the adapter itself? why do you want to do that for? It would be musch simpler if you provide more code for what you want to do

Comment: No the Intent is launched from a parent activity.  I want the "if(list!=null) in that activity to launch the RecyclerView list because there are previously created CardViews.  If the the list is null because there have been no CardViews created yet, then launch an activity for user input that creates a CardView that is set in the RecyclerView list.

Comment: Also, I am new to java and Android so what does the "return -1" do?  Did you choose "-1" as it returns a non-positive number?

Comment: I understand now.  Looks good, I just wonder if the "if(adapter...)" code will work if the RecyclerView list has not been created yet.  Will the activity be able to get an ItemCount number of zero from the adapter if the RecyclerView list hasn't been created yet?

Comment: You will be initializing the adapter in  onCreate right?

Comment: Ok great.  So I can learn, what does the "return -1" do? Did you choose "-1" as it returns a non-positive number?

Comment: Nothing particular,Any number less than or equal 0 will do,because we are checking the length of the list in the activity,And if the list is not initialized,I do not want it to trow a NullpointerException